# how to use sqlite cipher in default xcode application?

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

Im new to `sql cipher` and tried the link of `sql cipher` demo application. 
But when I run the application,it always enters in `else` part of following code.

```
sqlite3_key(sqlite3Database, key, (int)strlen(key));
if (sqlite3_exec(sqlite3Database, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    NSLog(@"Password is correct, or a new database has been initialized");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Incorrect password!");
}
```

I already have a database say `sqlDatabase.sql` with me.Now I want to encrypt it but this is not working. 
Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: because it prints "Incorrect password" all the time. 
Can you please tell me the way to encrypt the database ?

Comment: It is readonly database , and Im not able to encrypt it. For that I have had use this link -> https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/

Comment: Update the **question** to be more complete, it will make it easier for those who want to provide an answer. Then delete the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your plain-text SQLite database already exists, you will need to perform a `sqlcipher_export(…);` operation to encrypt it with SQLCipher.  More information can be found in the documentation [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export).

Comment: Thank you so much Nick. :) It helped !